# MVC updating session state into database via a api service does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, authentication, cookies

the idea is to create session and store it as a row in the database upon login, the  session is created and get an id every time a login occurs, however updating the session with the user information does not work for now. I might be missing some tiny detail. I'm new to MVC in general and never implemented session befor, I took over this application and need to work further on it. 
Code of the login page is strait forward nothing fancy other than there are two login ActionResults [Get] and [Post] one for creating the session(working) and the other suppose to update the session with the status and user information (not working!). Controller code looks like below:

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        SessionAid aid = new SessionAid();
        var mysession = aid.CreateSession();

        if (mysession.SessionID != 0)
        {
            Session["mySessionId"] = mysession.SessionID;

            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect("~/error");
        }

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Login model)
    {  
        string username = model.username;
        string password = model.password;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var session= new SessionData();

            Session["SessionUserID"] = model.username;
            Session["LastActiveTime"] = DateTime.UtcNow;
            Session["CookiesId"] = sessionData.CookieID;

            if (username == "name" && password == "password")
            {

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        return View();
        }
```

then there is the session controller where the update Session table with userId and cookieId method is implemented

```
public ActionResult SaveSession(SaveRequest saveRequest)
    {
        var respon = new SessionResponse();
            response.Session = new SessionData
            {
                SessionID = updatedSession.SessionID,                 
                CookieID = updatedSession.CookieID,
                SessionUserID = updatedSession.SessionUserID,

            };
            response.Success = true;
        }           
        return response;
    }
```

My question is how do I read the sessionId that is created in [HTTPGet] login method in the [HttpPost] login method, so I can update the session row in the database with cookieId and userID? What am I missing?

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use Session like this, given that there are much better/easier paths for building authentication?

Comment: Would you reference to a better/easier examples? I inherited this application from someone else and I need to finish that task. and it might be just easier to rebuild

Comment: I can't really give you a reference, but if you want something to get you started, it would be helpful to know what version of ASP.NET MVC this project is based on. From that I could add an answer with the skeleton of an authentication & authorization process.

Answer (score -1):

from what I understand, you can use the Session object you are storing the `SessionID` at.

ex:

```
int SessionId = Session["mySessionId"] as int;
```

this way you can get any thing you've stored in the Session object anywhere you want.

Comment: you see the session is created on the [HttpGet] login and the id is already created. Now I want to use same sessionId in my [HttpPost] login method. How do I do that?

Comment: as the code I wrote above, it will return the same ID generated in HttpGet one. Just use the same key you had above ("mySessionId")

Comment: The code does not compile as it gives the error {The operator as must be used within a reference type or nullable type}

Comment: I was giving you the idea how to do it, not the copy paste code that will work like a charm. it depends on the type of the session key you stored in the session object so you should replace `int` with the proper data type.